# CloneZilla HDD > SSD

Tags: windows-7, clonezilla

I am having a major issue trying to copy a 300GB HDD to a 120GB SSD. I have chosen to use Clonezilla as this has never let me down before, I have used Gparted to resize the larger drive down to just over 100GB. 
After thats done I boot into Windows and let ChkDsk do its thing before then booting back into Clonezilla. 
I can confirm that i can see both drives listed for selection and carefully chose the Source and Target, the first two smaller partitions copy over fine however on the third and 'main' partition the copy gets to between 50/70% and then freezes copying.

I have googled and tried as many of the different options that Clonezilla offers that I can but all do the exact same thing. We even tried setting up the partitions on the new drive and doing a partition to partition clone but same result. To make sure there is no issue with the SSD we even tried a larger drive but again this did the same thing.

I dont know how much difference it will make but the machine is a Dell Latitude laptop, the HDD is a Toshiba 300GB and the SSD is a 120GB Samsung.

Also posted here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2293868&p=13352257#post13352257 Please see here for fix if this is of interest.

Comment: If you solved this, post the solution as an answer. Don't point people to a forum thread somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to do a disk-to-disk clone with Advanced mode instead of partition by partition. In advanced mode, use the `-icds` options ("Skip checking destination disk size before creating partition table".

Something else to keep in mind is to make sure that Clonezilla is running live from the USB stick or DVD rather than running from RAM. If you have a dedicated Clonezilla disk this is the default (and I think only option), but if you are running Clonezilla from another distribution such as Parted Magic where the default is to write everything to RAM and run from there, Clonezilla may fail like this because basically you run out of RAM and it simply stops copying.

[Original](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2293868&p=13352291#post13352291)